# How to store proxy information for text mode browsers (e.g. links) permanently

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm looking for a command to store proxy information permanently for a text mode browser such as links. I tried the following:

- press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to get to the menus
- Setup | Network options | Proxies
- enter proxy information
- OK
- OK
- <kbd>ESC</kbd>
- Save options

This gets stored in `$HOME/.links2/links.cfg`

Answer (score 1):

The conventional way for a user to provide proxy configuration for Linux network programs is via environment variable `http_proxy`.  You can set an appropriate value for that variable via a command of this form:

```
export http_proxy=user:pass@dummy.proxy.com:port
```

Afterward, start `links` from the same shell.